# $_COOKIE['cookiefoo'], try to get a cookie

Tags: php, cookies, web-applications

I'm newbie with webapps and PHP.

I'm trying to get a cookie that it's not created yet, I mean, when I try to load a page that looks for a non-existent cookie I get an error, I tried to get rid of this with a try/catch but not success. This this the code I'm trying:

```
try{

    $cookie =  $_COOKIE['cookiefoo'];

    if($cookie){

          //many stuffs here
    }
    else
        throw new Exception("there is not a cookie"); 
}
catch(Exception $e){

}
```

How can I achieve this, any ideas, it would be appreciated it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to prevent an any warnings or notices from happening if the key is non-existent:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiefoo']) && !empty($_COOKIE['cookiefoo'])) {
    // exists, has a value
    $cookie =  $_COOKIE['cookiefoo'];
}
```

The same can be done with [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), though I think `isset` is more concise:

```
if(array_key_exists('cookiefoo', $_COOKIE) && !empty($_COOKIE['cookiefoo'])) {
    // exists, has a value
    $cookie =  $_COOKIE['cookiefoo'];
}
```

Comment: If you look for non-empty value, condition like:

if (!empty($_COOKIE['cookiefoo'])) is enough, no need for isset.

Comment: Either way, isset or empty does both really. I always use isset()

Comment: +1 for isset, !empty will return false for values like an integer 0, an empty array, and an empty string. Isset will only return false for null and a variable that is not set.